# 3 tables included similar to like or +1's way of doing it

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 2 tables

**pages**

```
page_id   post_id   pid  
 3421      2345      1357 
 3421      4567      2468
 3421      7891      1357
```

**usrs**

```
 pid      fname    lname 
 1357     john     bravo
 2468     ray      mexy
```

**Using the below statement**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT usrs.*,pages.* FROM usrs INNER JOIN pages ON 

 usrs.pid = pages.pid WHERE pages.page_id = '$pageid'"); // $pageid = 3421
```

It gives all the matches of page_id = 3421 in the form of array.

Something like this will echo the result

```
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        echo $row['post_id'] . " " . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];

o/p is   2345 john bravo 
         4567 ray  mexy
         7891 john bravo
```

Now the real question is, I have got another table to work on in this case

**Consider table 3 : total_likes**

```
   post_id   pid
    2345     3214
    2345     4123
    1245     4567
    2345     2367
```

users got the choice to like it and when user hits the `like button` hes `pid` is added with the `post_id` and now I want the number of likes for the specific `post_id` that is the number of rows for the specific `post_id.`

I want output to be something like this

```
         2345 john bravo     45 likes
         4567 ray  mexy      32 likes
         1357 john bravo     20 likes
```

I am not sure if its possible or not, since third table holds more values for post_id . It's like an array of value pointing to a value of an array `$row['post_id']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an extra subquery which separately calculate the number of records for every `post_id`.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.*
        c.likes, c.IsExist
FROM    pages a
        INNER JOIN usrs b
            ON a.pid = b.pid
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  post_id, 
                    COUNT(*) likes,
                    IF(SUM(pid = 1357) > 0, 'yes', 'no') IsExist
            FROM    total_likes
            GROUP   BY post_id
        ) c ON b.post_id = c.post_id
WHERE   a.page_id = 3421
```

Comment: but how do i echo the number of records? which statement to use? could you help me a little more.

Comment: use the query given, and to echo number of records: `echo $row['post_id'] . " " . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . " " . $row['likes'] . " likes";`

Comment: One more question kindly answer this.I would thanks a ton again. Is it possible to check if a specific pid exists in the returned rows ? I want to find a specific id in the returned list of likes. something like you know ..you and 40 others like this.. example I want to check whether pid=1357 exists or not in that returned number of likes . Thanks . and Thanks a ton

Comment: check the updated answer. `IF(SUM(pid = 1357) > 0, 'yes', 'no') IsExist` it returns `yes` if it exist otherwise `no`.

Comment: and where this value is stored in? in a variable $row['sum']??

Comment: hey this statement $row['IsExist'] throws an error undefined index . Could you please help me. I would be thankful to you

Comment: you just need to add `, c.IsExist`. see above.